# How to send a photo with compressing (in order to show in full size) in telegram using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

How to send a photo with compressing.
I have the code:

```py
client = TelegramClient(
    "session", 
    api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], 
    api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"]
)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    phone = input("Your phone: ")
    code = client.send_code_request(phone)
    myself = client.sign_in(phone, input("Your code: "))

# Sending a photo with description
client.send_message(
    777000, 
    "test",
    file="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/5295210/pub_60dd6ea6828fb32711ebfc76_60dd7130df4f6532136de7b1/scale_1200"
)
```

When i run this code i get:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVtgs.png)

**But i want this:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV96Z.png)

I tried to add `force_document=False` to arguments of method `.send_message` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumppy. `force_document=False` is working xD